# Precarious situation with git

Tags: git

Through my own carelessness I find myself with a Git repository with the following structure:

```
master
--------------------------------- M2 ----- C ---- D
                                  /
                                 /
develop                         /
--------------------- M1 ----- B 
                     /          \
                    /            \----- (all branches here) ----
TPQ                /              \
-------------- A -/                \---- (have the commit B) -----
                                    \
                                     \----- (as root) -----
```

**Problem:**
Upon recent viewing of the repository log, I identified the merge commit M1 as the place where everything goes south and hence I would like to get rid of it (if at all possible). Some changes in commit M1 shoudl stay on branch TPQ, let's call that M1a. The other part of the changes are best merged into develop (M1b).

Ideally, I'd like to end up with a following repository history

```
master
--------------------------------- M2 ----- C ---- D 
                                  /
                                 /
develop                         /
--------------------- M1b ---- B 
                      /         \
                     /           \----- (all branches here) ----
TPQ                 /             \
----- A --- M1a ---/               \---- (have the commit B) -----
                                    \
                                     \----- (as root) -----
```

**Question:** How can I achieve this transition?

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout A
# hack, hack    
git commit -m M1a
git checkout -b TPQ2
git checkout TPQ
git reset --hard TPQ2
git branch -d TPQ2

git checkout preM1
# hack, hack
git commit -m preM1b
git merge TPQ -m M1b
git checkout -b develop2
git cherry-pick develop # B
git checkout develop
git reset --hard develop2
git branch -d develop2

git checkout preM2
git merge develop -m "M2'"
git cherry-pick master~2..master
git checkout -b master2
git checkout master
git reset --hard master2
git branch -d master2
```

The result has one more commit than yours: the preM1b, where the remaining changes of M1 happen.